# I am attempting to sum two tables within themselves and then subtract the one table from the other. h

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to sum two tables together and subtract the one from the other. With a query, I can sum the two tables together, but am not able to subtract them. This is being attempted in Postgres Here are the tables:

```
 memberid   ticker  numshares   purchasedate    transactionid   purchaseprice
7   aapl    1   Jun 28, 2017    22  146
7   aapl    1   Jun 28, 2017    23  146
7   hog     1   Jun 28, 2017    24  55
7   aapl    10  Jun 28, 2017    25  1458
7   aapl    2   Jun 28, 2017    26  292
7   aapl    3   Jun 28, 2017    27  437
7   aapl    5   Jun 28, 2017    28  729
```

Here is the sells table:

```
memberid    ticker  numshares   selldate    sellid  sellprice
7   aapl    10  Jun 28, 2017    4   1458
7   aapl    15  Jun 29, 2017    5   2154
```

UPDATE: I got everything to work except one detail with the following 
Postgres statement:

```
`select qbuys.ticker, qbuys.total_purchaseprice-qsells.total_sellprice 
as current_total, qbuys.total_purchaseshares-qsells.total_sellshares as 
current_shares
from
(select sells.ticker, sum(numshares) as total_sellshares, 
sum(sellprice) as total_sellprice
from sells
where memberid = 7
group by ticker) as qsells, (select stocks.ticker, sum(numshares) as        
total_purchaseshares, sum(purchaseprice) as total_purchaseprice from 
stocks 
where memberid = 7
group by ticker) as qbuys
where qbuys.ticker=qsells.ticker`
```

The only issue remaining is that this does not return purchases that do not have a corresponding sell. It only spits out the total if there is a buy and a sell of the same ticker in each table. So the update I need is to have this spit out purchases that do not have a corresponding sell.

Comment: What issue? Have you tried doing that? Does it not work? What is the error?

Comment: I can sum the tables together using a similar statement as the SQL statement above. I am having trouble subtracting the sells table from the purchases table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using Postgres

Comment: @JoshuaWilcken My point was that if you say "I am having an issue" or "I am having trouble", then you need to tell us _what_ the problem is, i.e.: does nothing happen? do you get an error? do you get a result but it is wrong? does the computer explode? Without knowing what the problem is, people can only speculate, and that does not make for useful threads.

Comment: @underscore_d I understand. I believe that I have edited/updated my issue to the point of showing what the issue is and what it is returning.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this. What do you think?

```
select stocks.ticker, sum(stocks.numshares) - sum(sells.numshares) as total_shares, 
        sum(stocks.purchaseprice) - sum(sells.sellprice) as total_price 
from stocks 
left join sells
    on stocks.ticker = sells.ticket
where stocks.memberid = 7
group by stocks.ticker;
```

Comment: Oh man, this is so close. It is returning something, but just not quite. I updated yours just a little. 
     select stocks.ticker, sum(stocks.numshares) - sum(sells.numshares) as 
     total_shares, 
        sum(stocks.purchaseprice) - sum(sells.sellprice) as total_price 
        from stocks 
       left join sells
      on stocks.ticker = sells.ticker
      where stocks.memberid = 7
      group by stocks.ticker; 

The result gives me -106 total_sharesshares of aapl and -15256 total_price

Comment: @JoshuaWilcken I have updated it as per your comment. Next time feel free to edit.

Answer (score 0):

First, a sample schema w/ data (in postgres):

```
derek=# create table t1 (ticker varchar, numshares integer);
CREATE TABLE
derek=# create table t2 (ticker varchar, numshares integer);
CREATE TABLE
derek=# insert into t1 values ('aapl',10);
INSERT 0 1
derek=# insert into t1 values ('aapl',5);
INSERT 0 1
derek=# insert into t2 values ('aapl',3);
INSERT 0 1
```

Then the trick is to use inner queries for each aggregate function:

```
derek=# select t1a.ticker, buys, sells, buys-sells as position 
from (select ticker, sum(numshares) as buys from t1 group by ticker) as t1a 
join (select ticker, sum(numshares) as sells from t2 group by ticker) as t2a 
on t1a.ticker=t2a.ticker;
 ticker | buys | sells | position 
--------+------+-------+----------
 aapl   |   15 |     3 |       12
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables in order to subtract the sum of one column from the other.

```
SELECT
a.ticker
,sum(a.numshares) as Total_Sell_Shares
,sum(a.sellprice) as Total_Sell_Price
,sum(a.numshares) - sum(b.numshares) as Total_Shares
,sum(a.sellprice) - sum(b.purchaseprice) as Total_Price
FROM Sells A
JOIN Stocks B on a.ticker = b.ticker
GROUP BY a.ticker
```

Comment: I edited this query to fit my existing tables better. This query works as I want it to, except that it does not return purchases that do not have a sell. So for example, if I have only ever purchased 70 shares of AMZN but never sold any AMZN then it does not return my AMZN shares. If you have any ideas on that aspect, that'd be greatly appreciated.